# Preview doc files in a video conference using the SignalWire API

Tags: signalwire, signalwire-api

I am trying to show documents in a video conference that I've implemented using SignalWire. I want to show text and preview of the document to the all participants in a conference just like a presentation. Is there any function to do that in SignalWire?

I have tried the `play()` function like this

```js
roomSession.play({ url: "https://www.clickdimensions.com/links/TestPDFfile.pdf" });
```

but it only works with a video file.